# compare variable value inside an android service

Tags: android

I am running a service which checks which application is currently running in the foreground. the following code provides the currently foreground app name .

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)
getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
ListappProcesses=activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);

//get foreground App name 
 foregroundApp=appProcesses.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

Now I put this piece of code inside a service . the service checks every 15 secs if the foreground app has changed .the foreground variable updates if the foreground app changes . How can I compare when the value of foregroundApp variable changes ??

Answer (score 2):

```
  boolean isChanged = false;
  String packageName = appProcesses.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
  if(!packageName.equals(foregroundApp)) {
      foregroundApp = packageName;
      isChanged = true;
  }

  if(isChanged) {
        // do your implementation if another app comes to foreground
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the last package name in a static String, or you can save it with SharedPreferences... In the next check, you just compare the strings (with String.compare).

Answer (score 0):

You can store appname in another string and check it with foregroundApp string

Comment: I tried to store in another string . but every time the service starts the string gets initialized with previous value . How to get around this problem . Like I want to save in such a way that when the service starts next time the the value remains persistent ??